# Caesar cipher using Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I am just beginning to learn Python, this is my own take on a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) just looking at Python docs. I would like to know how I could have made it better and how would you rate this.  Is it any good?

```
#caeser cipher
import string

message = str(input("Enter the Message you want to encrypt: "))
shift = int(input("Enter the number of letters for cipher shift: "))

def cipher(message,shift):

    encList = []
    messageLst = []
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase * 2) 

    punct = list(string.punctuation)


    for i in message:
       messageLst.append(i)

    for i in messageLst :
        for j in alphabet:
            if i == j:
                replaceChar = alphabet[alphabet.index(j)+(shift)]
                encList.append(replaceChar)
                break
            elif i == " ":
                encList.append(i)
                break
            elif i in punct:
                encList.append(i)
                break
                
    encMessage = ""
    encMessage = encMessage.join(encList)
    #print(alphabet)

    #print(messageLst)
    #print(encList)
    print("Encrypted Message is : ", encMessage)



cipher(message,shift)
```

Answer (score 7):

## Alphabet list

Alphabet doesn't need to be a `list`, you can just use the `ascii_lowercase` string:

```py
# just a copy
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

# two copies
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase * 2


# alternatively
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
```

## Using the Modulo Operator

Instead of using two copies of `ascii_lowercase` to cover index overflows, you can use the modulo operation as shown by your linked Wikipedia entry:

```py
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

shift = 5

# index is in range(0, 25)
alphabet[(6 + shift) % 26]
'l'

# index would be > 25, so it loops back around
alphabet[(21 + shift) % 26]
'a'
```

## Cipher Lookup with a Dictionary

Now, what you could do is use a dictionary to build the lookups ahead of time so that you don't have to use `alphabet.index`:

```py
cipher_lookup = {char: alphabet[(i + shift) % 26] for i, char in enumerate(alphabet)}
```

Now, there's no more need to track indices:

```py
def cipher(message, shift):
    cipher_lookup = {char: alphabet[(i + shift) % 26] for i, char in enumerate(alphabet)}

    encrypted = []

    for letter in message:
        # simply look it up in the dictionary
        encrypted.append(cipher[letter])
```

## Checking for Punctuation

Use a `set` here, rather than a list. Membership testing for a `set`/`dict` is a time-constant operation, rather than O(N), where N is the length of the list:

```py
punct = set(string.punctuation)

'a' in punct
False

'.' in punct
True
```

However, you don't actually have to test for punctuation. You could instead use `dict.get` to return the value from the dictionary if it's there, and return the letter if it isn't:

```py
# say shift is 5
cipher_lookup.get('a', 'a')
'f'

# punctuation is not in the cipher
# so we just return that character
cipher_lookup.get('.', '.')
'.'
```

## Predefining `encMessage`

You can just use:

```py
enc_message = ''.join(enc_list)
```

## Variable Naming

Variable and function names are to be `snake_case` with all lowercase letters

## Function params

Separate your parameters in your function definitions with a space:

```py
def cipher(message, shift):
```

## `input`

You don't need to cast `message` to `str`, since `input` only outputs strings

## `if __name__ == "__main__"` Guard

This will allow you to import this function without executing the program if you wanted to reuse it:

```py
# This goes at the very bottom
if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = input("Enter the Message you want to encrypt: ")
    shift = int(input("Enter the number of letters for cipher shift: "))

    print(cipher(message, shift))
```

You can put your `message` and `shift` prompts here as well so that they don't execute unless you are running the program.

## Refactored

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet


def cipher(message, shift):
    cipher_lookup = {char: alphabet[(i + shift) % 26] for i, char in enumerate(alphabet)}

    encrypted_message = ""

    for letter in message:
        encrypted_message += cipher_lookup.get(letter, letter)

    return encrypted_message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = input("Enter the Message you want to encrypt: ")
    shift = int(input("Enter the number of letters for cipher shift: "))

    print(cipher(message, shift))
```

## String concatenation

It's not usually best practice to use string concatenation, but I think this is a good start to demonstrate the concepts of what's going on in the program. A better practice than the `for` loop would be to use a generator expression:

```py
encrypted_message = ''.join((cipher_lookup.get(letter, letter) for letter in message))
```

Answer (score 2):

[C.Nivs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/267760/100620) has made excellent points about:

- not needing to convert `alphabet` into a list
- using the Modulo Operator (`%`)
- storing the translations in a dictionary
- using `set`/`dict` and `in` for membership tests
- naming, spaces, unnecessary casts and initializations
- `__main__` guards

I won't repeat those here, but please study those and follow their advice on those points.

---

## Additional Code Review Points

### Loop Invariants

You wrote this double `for` loop:

```py
    for i in messageLst :
        for j in alphabet:
            if i == j:
                replaceChar = alphabet[alphabet.index(j)+(shift)]
                encList.append(replaceChar)
                break
            elif i == " ":
                encList.append(i)
                break
            elif i in punct:
                encList.append(i)
                break
```

The tests `i == " "` and `i in punct` are nested inside the inner loop, which loops `for j in alphabet`.  Notice that neither those tests nor the code executed based on passing either of those tests depends on `j`.  This is inefficient.

Consider a `messageLst` which contains `['z', 'e', 'b', 'r', 'a']`.  The first iteration of the outer loop

- assigns `'z'` to the variable `i`, and then
- executes the body of that loop, which is the inner loop.  That loop:

  - assign `j` to the first letter of `alphabet` (an `'a'`), and since `i == j` is false, goes on to check if `i` is a space, and if not, if `i` is a punctuation character.  Since both were false, the loop continues and,
  - assign `j` to the second letter of `alphabet` (a `'b'`), and since `i == j` is false, goes on to check if `i` is a space, and if not, if `i` is a punctuation character.  Since both were false, the loop continues and,
  - assign `j` to the third letter of `alphabet` (a `'c'`), and since `i == j` is false, goes on to check if `i` is a space, and if not, if `i` is a punctuation character.  Since both were false, the loop continues and,

Notice those checks for `i == ' '` and `i in punct` are redundantly executed ... 26 times in case of the letter `'z'`!

If those tests are moved out of the loop, we can get a more efficient implementation:

```py
    for i in messageLst :
        if i == " ":
            encList.append(i)
        elif i in punct:
            encList.append(i)
        else:
            for j in alphabet:
                if i == j:
                    replaceChar = alphabet[alphabet.index(j)+(shift)]
                    encList.append(replaceChar)
                    break
```

### Unnecessary looping

Consider just the inner loop:

```py
            for j in alphabet:
                if i == j:
                    ...
                    break
```

This searches `alphabet` for values `j` that equals `i`, and (due to the `break`) stops at the first occurrence.  When that occurrence is found, `j` will equal `i`.

This is a complicated way of writing:

```py
            if i in alphabet:
                j = i
                ...
```

In fact, you don't even need the extra `j` variable.  You can simply use `i` in the `...` code.

```py
            if i in alphabet:
                replaceChar = alphabet[alphabet.index(i) + shift]
                encList.append(replaceChar)
```

### Improved code

Fixing the loop invariant and removing the unnecessary looping (but without applying improvements from the other answer), we get:

```py
    for i in messageLst :
        if i in alphabet:
            replaceChar = alphabet[alphabet.index(i) + shift]
            encList.append(replaceChar)
        elif i == " ":
            encList.append(i)
        elif i in punct:
            encList.append(i)
```

... which is certainly an improvement over the original code.

## Batteries Included

C.Nivs also gave you improvements on string concatenation, culminating with a generator expression to produce the encrypted message.  We can do even better...

Python comes with a [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=trans#str.translate) function, which does a letter-by-letter substitution on a string ... which is exactly what the Caesar cipher is doing.

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def cipher(message: str, shift: int) -> str:
    """
    Encode a message using a Caesar Cipher with a user-defined shift on
    a 26 letter lowercase alphabet.
    """

    shift %= len(alphabet)
    code = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift])
    return message.translate(code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = input("Enter the Message you want to encrypt: ")
    shift = int(input("Enter the number of letters for cipher shift: "))

    print(cipher(message, shift))
```

*Note*: I've added a `"""docstring"""` and type-hints to the `cipher` function.  Both are extremely useful in Python development.  Make sure you study them.

Comment: Great answer! Minor nitpicks, just reading the code the part `code = ...` is a bit terse, adding `shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]` above would make it clearer. `len` of alphabet is called each time a new cipher is called. Maybe make it a constant `ALPHABET_LEN = len(alphabet)`. Some minor checking on the inputs would be nice. What happens if `shift` is not an int? Also some very brief `doctests` would make `cipher` clearer as it is a bit terse. `code` is better named `translation_table` or `cipher` =).

Comment: As a last comment =) `str` is imho not helping much. Typing hints should ideally _hint_ at what is going on. I find it clearer adding `from typing import Annotated` and then do something like `Plaintext = Annotated[str, "a plaintext to be ciphered"]`, `Ciphertext = Annotated[str, "an encrypted plaintext using a cipher"]` and then `def cipher(message: Plaintext, shift: int) -> Ciphertext:`.